# MSI-6837D laptop goes to hibernation when the lid is closed

Tags: power-management

I am using Ubuntu 12.10 in my MSI-6837D laptop, when I close the lid my system goes to suspension/hibernation and I cannot bring it back. 
I just want it to do nothing if I close the lid. I think something is wrong, because as you can see in the image below, I already selected the settings to do nothing when I close the lid, but is not working.

Any idea how can I fix this?

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps it is a option in your BIOS.

To see if this is the case you should reboot your laptop. As soon as you see any text on the screen you should press either F1, F6 or F10 (it varies from laptop to laptop, but often is says something like "Press F1 for Options" when the laptop is booting. Then you will enter the BIOS control center.

From there you will most likely have a lot of configuration options, and they all look different depending on which laptop you are using, so unfortunately I can't give specific instructions however a such option as "Behavior when lid is closed" is probably going to be under "Power" or "Display".

Comment: Could you please provide a bit more descriptive answer? This is more like a comment.

Comment: Sorry if my answer wasn't clear enough.
Some laptops have a option in the BIOS to set the default behavior when the laptops lid is closed. It Could perhaps be that setting "overwriting" the option set within Ubuntu, and therefor you will have to change the setting in BIOS.